# Many of metrics are empty when setting up istio 1.2.1 - what did i do wrong?

Tags: istio

I’m getting started with Istio (1.2.1) on k8s v1.15.0 - and everything looks good except many of the attributes are empty or “unknown”. Using the bookinfo sample app fields like destinationName, destinationApp, destinationWorkload, sourceName, sourceWorkload, etc are empty (or set to unknown), while other metrics are set. The log lines below were taken from the telemetry container on the telemetry pod while I curl’d the URL 100.96.76.176:9080/productpage.

All the pods have app and version labels set, and I’m not sure where else to look.

```
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.625780Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.140”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“g-demo”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“details.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:"",“httpAuthority”:“details:9080”,“latency”:“2.511893ms”,“method”:“GET”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:677,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“5662e4c0-8cd8-4212-b4e3-6fe8be75d3f5”,“requestSize”:0,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:178,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.628198Z”,“sentBytes”:313,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/details/0",“userAgent”:“curl/7.58.0”,“xForwardedFor”:“0.0.0.0”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.625458Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“unknown”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.140”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:"",“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“details.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:"",“httpAuthority”:“details:9080”,“latency”:“3.060349ms”,“method”:“GET”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:342,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“source”,“requestId”:“5662e4c0-8cd8-4212-b4e3-6fe8be75d3f5”,“requestSize”:0,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:178,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.628457Z”,“sentBytes”:307,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:“g-demo”,“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/details/0",“userAgent”:“curl/7.58.0”,“xForwardedFor”:“0.0.0.0”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.631186Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“unknown”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.152”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:"",“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“reviews.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:"",“httpAuthority”:“reviews:9080”,“latency”:“14.927949ms”,“method”:“GET”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:342,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“source”,“requestId”:“5662e4c0-8cd8-4212-b4e3-6fe8be75d3f5”,“requestSize”:0,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:375,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.646069Z”,“sentBytes”:549,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:“g-demo”,“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/reviews/0",“userAgent”:“curl/7.58.0”,“xForwardedFor”:“0.0.0.0”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.640811Z”,“instance”:“tcpaccesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“connectionDuration”:“0s”,“connectionEvent”:“open”,“connection_security_policy”:“unknown”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.5.90”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:"",“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“mongodb.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“protocol”:“tcp”,“receivedBytes”:0,“reporter”:“source”,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseFlags”:"",“sentBytes”:0,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“100.97.8.150”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:“g-demo”,“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“totalReceivedBytes”:0,“totalSentBytes”:0}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.644777Z”,“instance”:“tcpaccesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“connectionDuration”:“4.38701ms”,“connectionEvent”:“close”,“connection_security_policy”:“unknown”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.5.90”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:"",“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“mongodb.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“protocol”:“tcp”,“receivedBytes”:351,“reporter”:“source”,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseFlags”:"",“sentBytes”:429,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“100.97.8.150”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:“g-demo”,“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“totalReceivedBytes”:351,“totalSentBytes”:429}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] 2019-07-24T16:52:25.771171Z warn input set condition evaluation error: id=‘4’, error=‘lookup failed: ‘destination.service.host’’
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] 2019-07-24T16:52:25.771376Z warn input set condition evaluation error: id=‘4’, error=‘lookup failed: ‘destination.service.host’’
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.641665Z”,“instance”:“tcpaccesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“connectionDuration”:“0s”,“connectionEvent”:“open”,“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.5.90”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“g-demo”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:"",“destinationWorkload”:"",“protocol”:“tcp”,“receivedBytes”:277,“reporter”:“destination”,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseFlags”:"",“sentBytes”:0,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“100.97.8.150”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“totalReceivedBytes”:277,“totalSentBytes”:0}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.644179Z”,“instance”:“tcpaccesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“connectionDuration”:“3.633777ms”,“connectionEvent”:“close”,“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.5.90”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“g-demo”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:"",“destinationWorkload”:"",“protocol”:“tcp”,“receivedBytes”:351,“reporter”:“destination”,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseFlags”:"",“sentBytes”:429,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“100.97.8.150”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“totalReceivedBytes”:351,“totalSentBytes”:429}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.636470Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.8.150”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“g-demo”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“ratings.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:"",“httpAuthority”:“ratings:9080”,“latency”:“7.978662ms”,“method”:“GET”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:693,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“5662e4c0-8cd8-4212-b4e3-6fe8be75d3f5”,“requestSize”:0,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:48,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.644258Z”,“sentBytes”:166,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/ratings/0",“userAgent”:“curl/7.58.0”,“xForwardedFor”:“0.0.0.0”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.631485Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.152”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“g-demo”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“reviews.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:"",“httpAuthority”:“reviews:9080”,“latency”:“14.298546ms”,“method”:“GET”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:677,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“5662e4c0-8cd8-4212-b4e3-6fe8be75d3f5”,“requestSize”:0,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:375,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.645688Z”,“sentBytes”:555,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/reviews/0",“userAgent”:“curl/7.58.0”,“xForwardedFor”:“0.0.0.0”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.619969Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.4.119”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“g-demo”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“productpage.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:"",“httpAuthority”:“100.96.76.176:9080”,“latency”:“28.389479ms”,“method”:“GET”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:647,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“5662e4c0-8cd8-4212-b4e3-6fe8be75d3f5”,“requestSize”:0,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5179,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.648264Z”,“sentBytes”:5324,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/productpage",“userAgent”:“curl/7.58.0”,“xForwardedFor”:“0.0.0.0”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.619518Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“unknown”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.4.119”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:"",“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“productpage.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:"",“httpAuthority”:“100.96.76.176:9080”,“latency”:“29.187307ms”,“method”:“GET”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:224,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“source”,“requestId”:“5662e4c0-8cd8-4212-b4e3-6fe8be75d3f5”,“requestSize”:0,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5179,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.648640Z”,“sentBytes”:5318,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:“g-demo”,“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/productpage",“userAgent”:“curl/7.58.0”,“xForwardedFor”:“0.0.0.0”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] gc 74945 @116322.022s 10%: 0.015+35+105 ms clock, 0.12+3.6/8.2/36+845 ms cpu, 15->16->7 MB, 16 MB goal, 8 P
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.635940Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“unknown”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.8.150”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:"",“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“ratings.g-demo.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:"",“httpAuthority”:“ratings:9080”,“latency”:“8.73426ms”,“method”:“GET”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:362,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“source”,“requestId”:“5662e4c0-8cd8-4212-b4e3-6fe8be75d3f5”,“requestSize”:0,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:48,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:24.644626Z”,“sentBytes”:160,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:“g-demo”,“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/ratings/0",“userAgent”:“curl/7.58.0”,“xForwardedFor”:“0.0.0.0”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.628982Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.136”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“istio-system”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:“0”,“httpAuthority”:“mixer”,“latency”:“4.039738ms”,“method”:“POST”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:1152,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“242c989e-1d28-447b-b382-b194574cbdd7”,“requestSize”:825,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.632940Z”,“sentBytes”:141,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report",“userAgent”:"",“xForwardedFor”:“100.97.6.140”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.630094Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.136”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“istio-system”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:“0”,“httpAuthority”:“mixer”,“latency”:“3.013082ms”,“method”:“POST”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:1806,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“219ef409-2f09-4c89-acb2-d5da0ef45169”,“requestSize”:1475,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.633022Z”,“sentBytes”:141,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report",“userAgent”:"",“xForwardedFor”:“100.97.4.119”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.640448Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.136”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“istio-system”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:“0”,“httpAuthority”:“mixer”,“latency”:“1.354099ms”,“method”:“POST”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:964,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“968c7073-d926-43f7-b8bc-3c45e273c95c”,“requestSize”:637,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.641721Z”,“sentBytes”:141,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report",“userAgent”:"",“xForwardedFor”:“100.97.8.150”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.642777Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.136”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“istio-system”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:“0”,“httpAuthority”:“mixer”,“latency”:“129.565696ms”,“method”:“POST”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:827,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“7758c475-47ea-4dab-8240-0a9bf3f08839”,“requestSize”:501,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.772309Z”,“sentBytes”:143,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report",“userAgent”:"",“xForwardedFor”:“100.97.5.90”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.647082Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.136”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“istio-system”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:“0”,“httpAuthority”:“mixer”,“latency”:“125.353066ms”,“method”:“POST”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:1201,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“344b3520-0a89-427a-95f2-dcd83eb8c302”,“requestSize”:874,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.772387Z”,“sentBytes”:143,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report",“userAgent”:"",“xForwardedFor”:“100.97.6.152”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.648757Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.136”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“istio-system”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:“0”,“httpAuthority”:“mixer”,“latency”:“123.705739ms”,“method”:“POST”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:1180,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“3830bb1e-ee4a-4747-9b85-aa8632a05f10”,“requestSize”:849,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.772425Z”,“sentBytes”:143,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report",“userAgent”:"",“xForwardedFor”:“100.97.4.119”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.644416Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.136”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“istio-system”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:“0”,“httpAuthority”:“mixer”,“latency”:“128.10414ms”,“method”:“POST”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:1158,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“7ff3a60a-b806-4f09-9c12-28dc5652a413”,“requestSize”:831,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.772461Z”,“sentBytes”:143,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report",“userAgent”:"",“xForwardedFor”:“100.97.8.150”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.648347Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.136”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“istio-system”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:“0”,“httpAuthority”:“mixer”,“latency”:“124.187413ms”,“method”:“POST”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:1163,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“678d4923-e1d8-450b-a0c4-620c89e6e088”,“requestSize”:840,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.772496Z”,“sentBytes”:143,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report",“userAgent”:"",“xForwardedFor”:“100.97.6.157”}
[istio-telemetry-56d5966d6b-qj9z2 telemetry] {“level”:“info”,“time”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.644908Z”,“instance”:“accesslog.logentry.istio-system”,“apiClaims”:"",“apiKey”:"",“clientTraceId”:"",“connection_security_policy”:“none”,“destinationApp”:"",“destinationIp”:“100.97.6.136”,“destinationName”:"",“destinationNamespace”:“istio-system”,“destinationOwner”:"",“destinationPrincipal”:"",“destinationServiceHost”:“istio-telemetry.istio-system.svc.cluster.local”,“destinationWorkload”:"",“grpcMessage”:"",“grpcStatus”:“0”,“httpAuthority”:“mixer”,“latency”:“221.122459ms”,“method”:“POST”,“permissiveResponseCode”:“none”,“permissiveResponsePolicyID”:“none”,“protocol”:“http”,“receivedBytes”:1188,“referer”:"",“reporter”:“destination”,“requestId”:“780ce5c5-df66-47a8-abcf-349ff7a9cf3e”,“requestSize”:861,“requestedServerName”:"",“responseCode”:200,“responseFlags”:"-",“responseSize”:5,“responseTimestamp”:“2019-07-24T16:52:25.866003Z”,“sentBytes”:143,“sourceApp”:"",“sourceIp”:“0.0.0.0”,“sourceName”:"",“sourceNamespace”:"",“sourceOwner”:"",“sourcePrincipal”:"",“sourceWorkload”:"",“url”:"/istio.mixer.v1.Mixer/Report",“userAgent”:"",“xForwardedFor”:“100.97.6.152”}
```

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: Sir please check once about attributes I hope you ll get your answers like why mostly attributes are unknown and empty.
https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/mixer-overview/#attributes

Answer (score 0):

I am posting @ShreeGrossOptum's answer from the comments for better visibility and due to lack of response from the OP:

> Sir please check once about [attributes](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/mixer-overview/#attributes) I hope you ll get your
>   answers like why mostly attributes are unknown and empty.

Comment: Looking at that and the list of supplied attributes (https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/attribute-vocabulary/) it looks like these should be set (for example sourceName and sourceNamespace, although sourceNamespace is sometimes getting set).  If I use the helm chart for deployment everything seems to wire up properly, but not so when I use the operator from Banzai to deploy the components so I may need to just open an issue on it, but figure there's a better chance that I did something wrong but not sure where to look.